# How can I invalidate the jwt token after logout in Spring Boot with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I tried to implement an example with the usage of jwt token in Spring Boot. It covers register, login, refresh token and lastly logout process. I have a problem in logout process.

I tried to delete jwt token after logout but I think the process of invalidating the jwt token is the best way to handle with this process.

Here is the logout method of auth service shown below

Here is the logout request shown below

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class LogoutRequest {

    private String token;
}
```

Here is the logout method of controller

```
@PostMapping("/logout")
public ResponseEntity<String> logout(@RequestBody LogoutRequest request) {

    return ResponseEntity.ok(authService.logout(request));
}
```

Here is the getIdFromToken shown below

```
public Long getIdFromToken(String token){
    return Long.parseLong(extractClaims(token).getId());
}
```

Here is deleteByUserId shown below

```
@Override
public int deleteByUserId(Long userId) {

    User user = userService.findById(userId).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("User not found"));
    return refreshTokenRepository.deleteByUser(user);
}
```

How can I do that?

Here is the repo : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/bookdelivery)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Spring cannot logout properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75356073/java-spring-cannot-logout-properly)

Comment: @Toerktumlare No, I tried to implement the process of invalidating the token.

Comment: Use the OIDC Endpoint to Log Users Out of Auth0 - https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/login/logout/log-users-out-of-auth0

Comment: i looked at your filter, your filter does nothing except validate the signage of the token. If you provide a token, how does your filter know that the token has been "invalidated", well it doesnt? The funny thing here is that you are reimplementing session authentication using JWTs, why dont you just use session cookies?

Comment: @K.Nicholas is he using `auth0` i can't see that, this entire application looks like some home built own custom insecure authentication service by someone that doesnt know what FormLogin is, and he is rebuilding FormLogin from scratch but insisting on using JWTs instead of cookies which means he is loosing the benefits like `httpOnly` `Secured`and `same-site`

Comment: oauth or auth0 has the same odic logout endpoint, so I'm assuming that's the answer here. If you want to logout the JWT token, tell the server that issued it to you. I'm assuming at this point it's a bogus question since it should be obvious to anyone working with JWTs.

Comment: he doesnt have an issuer, the github he has provided he has built his own login and issues a jwt by himself https://github.com/Rapter1990/bookdelivery/blob/0d0394c882ba2b2e4008a7fbf90583c4dfad4cde/src/main/java/com/example/demo/service/impl/AuthServiceImpl.java#L60 so basically he has done the same misstake as everyone else, he is using JWT as a session. Most likely just found some poor tutorial saying that you should use JWTs as sessions

Comment: so the answer here is basically, he is using JWTs the wrong way and, he is using them as sessions which you should not. You dont use JWTs when you build this type of login because of the simple reason. You can not invalidate a JWT without either rotating the keys which invalidates all JWTs issued, or as he is trying to do, build a some sort of database to keep track of the issued JWTs, which means he needs to check in his filter everytime someone supplies a JWT if the JWT is logged out or not, which he currently doesnt. So his login endpoint does nothing, and his filter will gladly let them in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the answer here is the following:

What you have here is you have built a login, that at successful login you create your JWT in your service and hand out a token directly to the calling client. This is in oauth2 called an `implicit flow`and was deprecated from the oauth2 rfc because it was found to be insecure.

You also have built some sort of custom solution with some sort of thing you call a refresh token, which basically stores an id in some sort of storage.

So in principal, what you have actually built is some sort of Session authentication containing state, but completely custom, using JWTs.

You have tried to reinvent something that already exists in Spring Security which is called `FormLogin` which basically does all the things you want the only difference is that `FormLogin` uses cookies (which has additional security features like `httpOnly`, `Secured`, and `same-site`) but with JWTs.

So you are ending up with the same thing as `FormLogin` just less secure.

"Logging out" a JWT isn't really possible. You can only invalidate a JWT by letting it time out. Once a JWT is created with and expiration date is set and then signed, its signed. The contract has been written.

The problem with your code is that when someone supplies a JWT to your application is that your filter that checks the JWTs just checks if the signage and expiration is still valid.

```
// Checking the validity and expiration
Jwts.parserBuilder()
    .setSigningKey(getSignInKey())
    .build()
    .parseClaimsJws(authToken);
```

As long is the signage and time stamp is still valid your JWT will pass through here:

```
if (jwt != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
    // some other code
}
```

Which means you never check if the token is actually *logged out* in your custom refreshToken database, so the filter never understands that anything is logged out.

So you need to do a check here, but remember, you will then in each request done to your service, you have to possibly do 2 database calls. One to check if the token isnt logged out, and a second one to check if the user exists and log them in. Thats 2 database calls for every request, unless you store things in memory, or offload using caches etc.

The bottom line is that, you are basically trying to build `FormLogin` using JWTs, but less secure and possibly with less good performance and i strongly discourage you from doing so.

Answer (score 1):

You just can't invalidate a JWT.

What you can invalidate, are the sessions on the OAuth2 authorization server (which delivered the token) and OAuth2 client (to which the token was delivered).

Spring Security client implementation can be configured to do both: perform logout from the authorization server with a post-logout handler on the client.

The thing is that apparently, the application configuration and flows used have nothing to do with OAuth2, which ends to something pretty unsafe and inefficient as pointed in the other answer. You should just trash all that and opt for:

- [`formLogin`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html) (with sessions and CSRF protection) if you don't need externalized authentication (SSO with the rest of your information system) or secured inter micro-services calls
- proper OAuth2 otherwise (with confidential client on your server)